# Python: Save keywords in a list and add another list to the single words in it

Tags: python

I want to have a global variable. In the variable I want to save a list of keywords. And after I want to add to every keyword another list of booleans. My first try was to do it like this:

```
global variable = {}
for word in wordlist:
    variable[word]
    for boolean in booleanlist:
        variable[word].append(True)
```

I get an error at "variable[word]" because of an KeyError. This should be the part there I add the word into my list.
So after I want to count all the Trues for each word like:

```
variable[wordA].count(True)
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Why/What are you (not) asking?

Comment: I don't understand the line ' variable[word]'. What are you trying to do ? There is no assignment here, no side-effect.

Comment: @TimF I tried to add the word in the list. But it doesn't work for me ...

Comment: @LogicStuff forgot to say that I get a Error in "variable[word]" there I want to add the word to the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix the *KeyError* you can do the following thing:

```
variable = {}
for word in wordlist:
    variable[word] = []
    for boolean in booleanlist:
        variable[word].append(True)
```

Note that in this code snippet every *keyword* has the same *list of Booleans*, but that's what you have given to us.

---

**edit:** removed the *global* declaration, it was there only because the OP had it.

Comment: Some feedback about the negative vote would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be that the fact that you left the `global` in the code has something to do with it.

Comment: @Matthias thanks for your opinion

Answer (score 2):

Can't figure out exactly what you need but it look like a Dict of Boolean List

```
wordlist = ["toto", "tata", "tutu"]
booleanlist = [True, False]

variable = {word: booleanlist for word in wordlist}
```

Give you:

> {'toto': [True, False], 'tutu': [True, False], 'tata': [True, False]}

```
variable['tutu'].count(True)
```

> 1

Hope to be helpfull here,
cheers